# compare Joda-Time time zones

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

In my application using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), I need to compare two time stamps (either [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) or [LocalDateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html))...if `t1.isBefore(t2)` then allow the user else pop up an error...

say, I have t1 as `2013-03-01T10:17:55.872` (always US/EASTERN `-0500` or `-0400` Standard offset)

but, my t2 will change depedning on the location of the user and I can get the offset as well as time, say t2 as `2013-03-01T14:48:09.000` and offset of `-0800`.

How can compare these two using 'isBefore'?

any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you have them both as `DateTime` values, you should just be able to use [`isBefore`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isBefore%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29), as `DateTime` inherits that from `AbstractInstant`.

However, I'd be quite tempted to convert them plain `Instant` values first (via `toInstant`). That way it's clearer that you *don't care* about the local date/time; you're *only* interested in the instants they represent. (I'm assuming that really is the kind of comparison you want. If you actually want to compare the local date/time, convert both to `LocalDateTime` instead!)

Comment: `t1` will end up in LocalDateTime always and need to convert it to dateTime with standard offset...

Comment: @user1609085: Standard offset, or the relevant offset for Eastern time? Bear in mind that around DST transitions, local values can be ambiguous (or invalid). Either way, you basically need to get to the relevant instants in time...

Comment: Converted to Instant and it works for me..! Thank you. to get the relevant offset, I can use the Id(Hardcoded) like, `DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")` right?

Comment: @user1609085: Yup, that's fine - but just be aware of the DST transition possible issue. Joda Time doesn't let you choose how that's handled IIRC, so you just need to be aware of what *will* happen...

Comment: I am dealing with something similar as well .. Here's what I am trying to do -  DateTime estDT = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Puerto_Rico")).withMillisOfSecond(0);
DateTime londonDT = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London")).withMillisOfSecond(0);;  and then I do    System.out.println("Comparison " + londonDT.isBefore(estDT));
  System.out.println("Comparison " + londonDT.isAfter(estDT));      Interestingly enough, I get 'false' from both sysout stmts. Can anyone please explain what will be the right way of doing this comparison?

Comment: @FSP: That comment doesn't really tell us much about what you're trying to do or whether you're having problems. I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I pressed enter to indent the code better and hence you saw incomplete text.. Anyhow, I wish I could make my comment easier to read.

Comment: @FSP: You can't indent code within a comment - and indeed you're not meant to. If you've got enough code that you need it to be laid out, you should be asking a new question...

Comment: @JonSkeet just added a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172782/comparing-two-joda-datetime-objects