# Comparing two Joda-Time DateTime objects

Tags: java, jodatime

I am dealing with something very similar to what has been asked here - [compare Joda-Time time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165788/compare-joda-time-zones/15165833?noredirect=1#comment24863944_15165833) but it does not seem to work for me.

Here's a piece of code which I am testing [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) with -

```
 DateTime estDT = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Puerto_Rico")).withMillisOfSecond(0); 
 DateTime londonDT = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London")).withMillisOfSecond(0);

    System.out.println("Comparison " + londonDT.isBefore(estDT)); 
    System.out.println("Comparison " + londonDT.isAfter(estDT));
```

Interestingly enough, I get 'false' from both the sysout statements above. Can anyone please explain what will be the right way of doing this comparison?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're creating two DateTime instances probably representing the same instant in time, but with different time zones. Neither is before or after the other.

The time zone just affects how the date/time methods like `getHourOfDay()` convert the instant in time.

Comment: Technically, londonDT represents a moment *after* estDT as points on the timeline of the Universe. Two separate lines of code mean two separate samplings of the computer's clock, so the 2nd line happened later than the 1st. DateTime has a resolution of milliseconds, so if both those lines of code happened to execute within the same millisecond of the computer's clock then they would be equal to one another. This is pure luck (chance). Depending on if the Java thread got delayed/suspended during its execution, or if it ran on a slower computer, those two DateTimes may have been different.

Comment: We were both a little too strong. The two *probably* represent the same instant in time, given the calls to withMillisOfSecond(0). However, they could differ, if they happened to execute on different seconds (e.g., millis=999 and millis=0). If the same instant in time were actually desired, the withZone() method would be more reliable than getting the instant twice. However, it's more likely that the OP wants two different instances in time, provided as input.

Answer (score 63):

[isAfter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isAfter%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) and [isBefore](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isBefore%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) methods compare dates by millis (ignoring time zone).

In your example, the dates have equal millis.

```
System.out.println(londonDT.getMillis() == estDT.getMillis());
```

will print `true`.

Expressions

```
londonDT.isBefore(estDT) 
londonDT.isAfter(estDT)
```

are equal to

```
londonDT.getMillis() < estDT.getMillis()  
londonDT.getMillis() > estDT.getMillis()
```